# Grouping all your apps into folder

Tags: android

I work for a govt. department and we have more than 10 android apps which are regularily used for sending reports. There is a need of all the installed apps to be grouped in a folder on Home Screen and App list in android.

Can I have any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create small app in which you can list all those app. And on click from this app you can start your other apps

Comment: Hi, @Arshad, I have made an app as you said and it works find. But requirement is to show all our apps grouped as google groups all its app in a folder and show it on home screen on device. Hope you understand